# Bigger "dot" as accent symbol

Tags: accents

I want to make an bigger (bolded) dot symbol over a letter but when I use the package "accents" it collides (I presume) with other used packages and I receive an error message:

```
   ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.
```

and the source of the problem is:

```latex
$\dot{A}$
```

The function `\dot{}` works without problems but it causes an error only if I use the package "accents" even if I do not use any function of the package.

```latex
\usepackage{accents}
```

EDITED (added a Minimum Not Working Example):

```latex
\documentclass[16pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Custom font
\usepackage{fontspec}
% For math symbols ...
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Bigger dot symbol
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

haahahahaha $\dot{A}$

\end{document}
```

In the example code above it obviously collides with `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimum working example with your question, though; as it is, it's on us to do the work to test your problem.  Furthermore, making the MWE will often answer your question by itself.

Comment: Indeed, a brief test shows that a MWE compiles with or without the `\usepackage{accents}`, without errors (though also without any visible difference that I can see).  Making a MWE will probably show you that your problem lies elsewhere.